# Scheduled task for Windows Phone 7.0 class library

Tags: windows-phone-7, scheduled-tasks, class-library, background-agent

Hi all
I want to add scheduled task facility to my class library. User should be able to get the location periodically and he should be able to determine time interval, using classes in my class library. It must be compatible with Windows Phone 7.0. I found some solutions using Microsoft.Phone.Schedule namespace, however it is available for only 7.1 and 8, and I cannot add it to my 7.0 library. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202941%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) provides a solution for 7.1 and 8. Is there any way that I can do this job in Windows Phone 7.0.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer .. but why do not you upgrade your library to 7.1? It will make many thinks easier for you. There is no need to maintain 7.0 apps because 7.1 is mandatory and only devices running 7.1 can download apps from the store.

Comment: I didn't know that actually. Thank you for this really critical info. I'll take your advice.